# WCF: Dynamic address for service reference on client

Tags: debugging, wcf, release, service-reference

Basically, I have an application that needs to consume a WCF Service (Calculator.svc). While in debugging, the service is being hosted on my local machine, but in release the service is being hosted on an IIS server.

Debug Address: `http://localhost/MyProj/Services/Calculator.svc`
Release Address: `http://www.mycompany.com/Services/Calculator.svc`

If I don't add a service reference and construct the service by hand, this isn't an issue anymore. But, if I add a service reference to my localhost address, then how do I dynamically change that during release mode?

---

NOTE: I do realize I can create a new CalculatorClient and feed in my own Binding and EndpointAddress, but is that the proper way to do it?

```
CalculatorClient client;

#if NOT DEBUG
Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding("MyConfig");
EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://www.mycompany.com/Services/Calculator.svc");

client = new CalculatorClient(binding, remoteAddress);

#else
client = new CalculatorClient();
#endif
```

Is there an easier way or more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two options:

1) Change the values in `app.config` in your build/deployment script.

2) Use the same address for both. On your dev machine this can be setup by adding an entry in your `HOSTS` file pointing `www.mycompany.com` to localhost. After this is done you set up a web site in iis for the host header `www.mycompany.com` and serve the project from there.